# Enable Picklist Field Based on Checkbox Value In Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, disable

I have a requirement wherein if checkbox is `true`, picklist field must be enabled. If checkbox is `false`, picklist field must be disabled. But in default, picklist field must be disabled.

Enabling/disabling of picklist field is controlled by a javascript function also embedded in my visualforce page. However, each time I click the checkbox field, picklist field remained disabled.

How can I make this work with regards to the html tags inside the visualforce page?

**Vf page portion:**

```
<apex:column headerValue="Checkbox Field">
    <center>
        <table>
            <tr>      
                <td><apex:inputcheckbox id="cb" value="{!acc.Checkbox_Field__c}" onclick="check(this)"/></td>    
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>                                
</apex:column> 

<apex:column headerValue="Picklist Field">   
    <center>
        <table>
            <tr>                      
                <apex:selectList id="pf" value="{!acc.Picklist_Field__c}" disabled="true" size="1">  
                    <!--PickListFields came from a method in apex class....-->
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!PickListFields}"/> 
                </apex:selectList>  
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>    
</apex:column>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>

    function check(obj)
    {

        if((obj.checked == true)){

            document.getElementById('{!$component.pf}').disabled=false;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('{!$component.pf}').disabled=true;

        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid doing it with raw javascript & html, unless the element you're trying to interact with it also plain html. Salesforce puts a lot of extra information into other input elements that it manages under the surface. Trying to interact with a element may not work as expected unless you're using apex functionality. A great example of this is lookups, try inspecting one using your browser. You'll notice a additional set of input tags used to manage the old & new information, for a single field.

---

I usually manage behavior like this by making the attribute conditional, then re-rendering the element anytime the field is changed.

Something like:

```
<apex:selectList id="pf" value="{!acc.Picklist_Field__c}" disabled="{!NOT(acc.Checkbox_Field__c)}" size="1">
```

You'll want to make sure that your `Checkbox_Field__c` is set to `false` when your component loads in order to start with the picklist disabled.

Then, instead of a javascript function, use a `apex:ActionFunction`. Same idea, but this allows talking directly to our controller, as well as rerender targets.

```
<apex:actionFunction name="UpdatePicklist" rerender="pf">
    <apex:param value="" name="CheckBox" assignTo="{!acc.Checkbox_Field__c}" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Make sure your checkbox has a event handler for this function:

```
<apex:inputcheckbox id="cb" value="{!acc.Checkbox_Field__c}" onchange="UpdatePicklist(this.value);" />
```

Now, when you modify the checkbox, a javascript function runs, which updates the value stored in the checkbox field, then rerenders the section with a conditional disabled attribute, which will either enable it or disable it, depending on the value.

Seems like you have the right idea, just need to execute it differently.

---

Disclosure: I'm writing this on my lunch break without actually testing the code. Some stuff might not be right, like not having an `action` attribute on the actionFunction or using the param to update a variables field.

Also, if you have existing javascript, ie, you need this function for more than just updating a fields disabled attribute, you can call an `actionFunction` inside javascript code, letting you write an event handler as normal, and call `UpdatePicklist` inside that code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are using `{!$Component.pf}` to find the correct `select` html element to update. This doesn't work because Salesforce generates the `id` before serving the pages and the generated string depends on placement of your component within other components.

Instead of relying on the `id` attribute we can safely use `styleClass` attribute with slight modifications to your code as follows.

Add a variable for generating unique class names

```
<!-- declare a visualforce variable outside of your pageBlockTable -->
<apex:variable value="{!0}" var="index" />
```

Add `styleClass` attribute and assign unique classNames using `index` variable

```
<apex:column headerValue="Checkbox Field">
    <!-- increment the value of this index inside apex:column -->
    <apex:variable var="index" value="{!index+1}" />
    <center>
        <table>
            <tr>      
                <td>
                    <!-- generates a unique className and assign it to checkbox field -->
                    <apex:inputCheckbox id="cb" styleClass="checkbox-{!index}" value="{!acc.Checkbox_Field__c}" onclick="check(this)"/>
                </td>    
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>                                
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Picklist Field">   
    <center>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <!-- generates a unique className and assign it to select field -->                      
                <apex:selectList id="pf" styleClass="select-{!index}" value="{!acc.Picklist_Field__c}" disabled="true" size="1">  
                    <!--PickListFields came from a method in apex class....-->
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!PickListFields}"/> 
                </apex:selectList>  
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>    
</apex:column>
```

Update the JavaScript function to get elements by className

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check(elem){
        var className = 'select-' + elem.className.split('-')[1];
        var selectFields = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
        for(var i=0; i<selectFields.length; i++) {
            // using for loop, but it going to be just one element
            if(elem.checked == true) {
                selectFields[i].disabled = false;
            } else {
                selectFields[i].disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Hope this helps.

**PS:** Make sure you generated classNames which are not there in your CSS otherwise CSS can modify the style of your markup.